# How to make two rails routes go to the same controller when namespaced?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

The intention is to create the following two urls:

- http://example.com/widgets/edit
- http://example.com/posts/1/widgets/edit

Where "posts" are resources, and "widgets" are not (it's just a URL the client wants)

I want both of these routes to go to the SAME controller.

I have a setup like this in routes.rb:

```
 namespace :widgets do
   get :edit
 end

 resources :posts do
   namespace :widgets do
     get :edit, to: "widgets#edit"
   end
 end
```

a quick rake routes/grep shows these go to two seperate controllers:

```
 rake routes | grep widgets
 /widgets/edit(.:format)                widgets#edit
 /posts/:post_id/widgets/edit(.:format) widgets/widgets#edit
```

I have both of the urls I want, but the second one is going to a different controller! I've tried a whole bunch of different configurations with no luck - how do I bust out of that additional "widgets" namespace in the second route without letting go of this URL that the client wants?

**I am using rails 3.2, so "concerns" are out. Upgrading not an option right now.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check route file once. May be u'll have some dynamic routes before '/posts/:post_id/widgets/edit' which might be getting hit.

Comment: The above content is all that is in the routes file (I set myself up a little demo).

Comment: Try `namespace :widgets, controller: :widgets do` within the resource

Comment: Would treating `:widgets` as a singular resource be an option? Then everything else will work pretty much out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate that route from being nested above your resource route block.

get "posts/:post_id/widgets/edit" => 'widgets#edit'.

Your nested namespace is adding the widget slug and your desired action is adding the model slug as well.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Fully aware that this is not very railsy, but I'm working to a tight deadline on a legacy system!